# Externalization Java Object - HashMap

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, serializable, externalizable

[Externalizable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) seems to be hard to use. Reasons

1. Strings in an object can be null. So, I have create and serialize flags to mentioned weather or not to do inReader.readUTF()
2. For Java Lists its even more hard.

I am not sure, what is the best way to externalize a java HashMap, since I would know at reading time, how many keys are there and if any value is null.

Comment: Serialize with Externalizable interface.

Comment: Why are you using `Externalizable`? Are you working on a legacy application?

Comment: The serialization process of a HashMap is talked about in the Java JDK classdocs briefly under [Serialized Forms (HashMap)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/serialized-form.html#java.util.HashMap): "*The capacity* of the Hashtable (the length of the bucket array) is emitted (int), followed by *the size* of the Hashtable (the number of key-value mappings), followed by *the key (Object) and value (Object) for each key-value mapping*..". Can't the (Externalization) class responsible for the serialization use the same process? (The size of a HashMap and List is known.)

Comment: Hmm. Good question. There could be many reason for it, but I am using it for a) perfomance, b) Sometimes Hibernate injects its own proxy objects which may error out while deserialization (different Serial ID)

Comment: Nobody said you have to use read/writeUTF(). You can serialize the strings as Objects, which takes care of the null for you.